# Vertical centering within a variable height div

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I have a page split down the middle into two vertical columns, #split-left and #split-right. Each column is 50% of the page's width.

In the left column is a contact form with a potentially variable height if the number of fields changes.

On the right side, I'd like to have the height of #split-right match that of #split-left, with the text centered vertically.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
#regular-page { display: table; }
#split-left { display: table-cell; width: 50%; }
#split-right {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
}
```

The layout breaks on mobile view. You could remove the `#content { width: 320px; }` but still breaks.

Comment: Thanks, azeos--that works great. Still need to fix some things on the mobile side for sure. I appreciate the help.